# Jslider should fire change event when it come to rest

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I have one slider in my `JAVA` application.I have written change listener for that slider. Here is the code i have written

```
jSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,0,30,2);
        jSlider.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 10));
        jSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
        jSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(2);
        jSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
        jSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
        jSlider.setBounds(76, 564, 586, 55);
        jSlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                textField.setText(String.valueOf(jSlider.getValue()));
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jSlider);
```

This code gives the continuous changing values of the slider.

but i want the value of rest position of the slider.
What should I write to get the value only for the rest position?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can also use

```
jSlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                JSlider source = (JSlider)e.getSource();
                if(!source.getValueIsAdjusting())
                {
                    //textField.setText(String.valueOf(source.getValue()));
                    int gain = source.getValue();
                    //System.out.println("***** GAIN ***** "+gain);
                    GetGain g = new GetGain(gain);
                }
            }
        });
```

Above code also gives the value for the rest position of the slider.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, what you can do is insert a "forced delay" between the time the `stateChanged` event is raised and the time that the `textField` is updated.

This basically means we are waiting for a fixed period of time between when the `stateChanged` method was last called BEFORE we try and update the `textField`.

Because we don't want to block the Event Dispatching Thread, because it would stop any new events from being processed, I've used a `javax.swing.Timer`.

Basically, whenever the `stateChanged` method is called, I restart the timer.  Once the events stop, the timer is allowed to complete and triggers a `actionPerformed` event, which allows us to update the `textField`...easy ;)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class TestSlider01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestSlider01();
    }

    public TestSlider01() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JSlider slider;
        private JTextField textField;

        private Timer slideTimer;

        public TestPane() {

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            textField = new JTextField(20);

            slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 30, 2);
            slider.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 10));
            slider.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
            slider.setMajorTickSpacing(2);
            slider.setPaintTicks(true);
            slider.setPaintLabels(true);
            slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
//                    textField.setText(String.valueOf(slider.getValue()));
                    slideTimer.restart();
                }
            });
            slideTimer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    textField.setText(String.valueOf(slider.getValue()));
                }
            });
            slideTimer.setRepeats(false);
            add(slider, gbc);
            add(textField, gbc);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I've deliberately used a largish value for the delay, you may wish to play with it...

Also, `setBounds` is a very bad idea.  I would invest the time into learning the layout manager API, it will save you a lot of heart-ache in the long run ;)